# Spring Model Object is not rendering

Tags: spring, jsp

I am trying to return a  message  string as a model object from my controller on some JSP page(**success.jsp**). But the message is not rendering on the target page. Here what I am getting on the page(**success.jsp**):

> Welcome.. ${message}

Here is my controller method from where the JSP page is returning:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register",method=RequestMethod.POST)
      public ModelAndView registerUser(@ModelAttribute("dtoUserInfo") DtoUserInfo dtoUserInfo)
      {
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            serviceUserInfo1.registerUser(dtoUserInfo);
            modelAndView.setViewName("success");
            modelAndView.addObject("message","New User");
            return modelAndView;
      }
```

Here is my jsp page content(**success.jsp**)

Welcome.. ${message}

Comment: that is correct, if it wasn't you woul dget an error message... what does the jsp look like, is there an exception ?

Comment: I am getting no exception for this.

Comment: what does the jsp look like, are there any debug logs available /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your JSP to process EL expression.

To do so add this line in your jsp:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Comment: Worked..Thanks Benoit Wickramarachi